# Resolving ambiguity with Lombok RequiredArgsConstructor

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I am dealing with the following class definition from the sample source code that comes with the book [Spring in Action 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294942):

```
package tacos;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
@Entity
public class Ingredient {

  @Id
  private final String id;
  private final String name;
  private final Type type;

  public static enum Type {
    WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
  }

}
```

I am getting the following compile error upon trying to instantiate the Ingredient with arguments:

```
reference to Ingredient is ambiguous
both constructor Ingredient(String,String,Type) in Ingredient and constructor Ingredient(String,String,Type) in Ingredient match
```

Other  than "delomboking" the class definition, are there any suggestions?

**Addendum**

Since the first suggested fix (*Try removing the Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor*) is not working, let me go ahead and share the invocation code as well.

Here is the IngredientRepository interface:

```
package tacos.data;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import tacos.Ingredient;

public interface IngredientRepository 
         extends CrudRepository<Ingredient, String> {

}
```

And here is the TacoCloudApplication class that is giving the compile error:

```
package tacos;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import tacos.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.data.IngredientRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TacoCloudApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(IngredientRepository repo) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
      @Override
      public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        repo.save(new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE));
        repo.save(new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE));
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I've seen that ever. It's it possible the `@Entity` annotation also creates a constructor? Try removing the Lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor` one.

Comment: Your entire code works fine for me.

Comment: Check if you are running lombok twice (eg. added two times the lombok processor).

Comment: are you using IntelliJ ? check what plugins you have on it

Comment: In response to the question "are you using IntelliJ ? check what plugins you have on it" I would like to mention that I am using NetBeans 8.2.